# Trying to show a form inside fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Im trying to When I click in my "create posts" link I want to show the form that I have in my "post-create.php" in a fancybox but Im not having sucess with this. It is possible?

I have a **menu.php** file with a link for other pages:

```
<li><span>Manage Posts</span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="dashboard.php?ac=posts/posts-create" class="fancybox">Create Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="dashboard.php?ac=posts/posts"> Edit Post</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Then I have a **post-create.php** file with a form:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label class="line">
<span class="data">Image:</span>
<input type="file" class="fileinput" name="thumb" size="60" style="cursor:pointer; background:#FFF;" />
</label>

<label class="line">
<span class="data">Title:</span>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])) echo $f['title']; ?>" />
</label>

<label class="line">
<span class="data">Content:</span>
<textarea name="content" class="editor" rows="15"><?php if(isset($_POST['content'])) echo htmlspecialchars($f['content']); ?></textarea>
</label>
</form>
```

Then is my **fancybox** script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
         iframe: {
            preload: false
        }



    });
})
```

Comment: `$("fancybox")` is searching for an html tag `<fancybox>`, which doesn't exist. You probably want `$('.fancybox')` (element with CSS **class** of fancybox) or `$('#fancybox')` (element with DOM ID fancybox).

Comment: Thanks, thats right, but the problem continues :/